# dimension of kernel of linear transformation on vector space of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be the set of $n \times n$ matrices thought of as vector space of $n^2$ dimension over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $F_A: M_n(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be defined by $B \mapsto AB$.  Show that $\ker(F_A)$ for any $A$ has dimension $kn$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$

---

What I have tried that is that since $\ker(F_A)$ is finite dimensional, it is isomorphic to a subspace spanned by some of the canonical basis of $M_n(\Bbb C)$, which I call $B_{ij}$, then I showed that $AB_{ij}=0$ iff $i^{th}$ column of $B$ is 0, which tells me that the $i^{th}$ row of any matrix in the kernel must be free, but then I cannot finish the argument.

Comment: What is your try?

Comment: What I have tried that is that since $Ker(F_A)$ is finite dimensional, it is isomorphic to a subspace spanned by some of the canonical basis of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, which I call $B_{ij}$, then I showed that $AB_{ij} = 0$ iff $i^th$ column of $B$ is $0$, which tells me that the $i-th$ row of any matrix in the kernel must be free,  but then I cannot finish the argument.

Answer (score 1):

First note that if $A$ is invertible, the only $B$ in the kernel is the zero matrix. This is because we can multiply $A^{-1}$ on both sides of $AB=0$ to get $B=0$. In this case, $\ker(F_A)=0$ has dimension $0$. The other extreme is when $A$ is the zero matrix. In this case any $B$ satisfies $AB=0$, and $\ker(F_A)=n^2$.

Now suppose that $A$ has rank $n-k$, that is, $k$ of the columns of $A$ can be written as linear combinations of the other linearly independent $n-k$ columns. We claim that $\ker(F_A)$ has dimension $kn$. Let us denote the columns of $A$ as $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ and the $(i,j)$-entry of $B$ as $b_{ij}$. To find the dimension of the kernel, we solve for $B$, that is, look for restrictions on its entries $b_{ij}$. For every $j$ between $1$ and $n$, by the definition of matrix multiplication, we have
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^n b_{ij} a_i = 0,
\end{equation}
where the $0$ means the zero column, or more precisely, the $j$-th column of $0=AB$.

The previous sum is a system of $n$ equations with $n$ variables/unknowns, the unknowns being the $b_{ij}$. We write the $k$ dependent columns of $A$ as linear combinations of the other $n-k$ columns. Then the system becomes an overdetermined system with $k$ free variables. We can let the $k$ free variables to have any value, and the other $(n-k)$ variables $b_{ij}$ are determined uniquely after that because once we have chosen values for the free variables the system is $n-k$ by $n-k$ with invertible coefficient matrix. We can do this for every column $j$ of $B$, so the dimension of the kernel is $kn$.

Furthermore, to find a basis for the kernel, let one of the free variables be $1$ and the others $0$, and then solve for the other $b_{ij}$. The resulting matrix is one basis element of the kernel.

For example, if $n=4$ and the last two columns of $A$ are dependent on the first two, we can choose the last two rows of $B$ freely, and the first two rows of $B$ will be determined uniquely once the last two rows are specified.

Answer (score 0):

For a matrix $B$, let $B_i$ denote the $i^{th}$ column of $B$. We can think of a matrix as just a tuple of its column vectors, ie $B \in M_n (\mathbb C)$ is thought of as $(B_1, \dots, B_n) \in (\mathbb C^n)^n$. We do this because the columns of $AB$ are found by applying $A$ to each column of $B$, so $F_A(B_1, \dots, B_n) = (AB_1, \dots AB_n)$. Then for $F_A(B) = 0$, we must have $A B_i = 0$ for all $i$. That is, each $B_i$ must be in $ker(A)$ where $A$ is thought of as a linear map on $\mathbb C^n$.

Since $B \in ker(F_A)$ if and only if each column $B_i \in ker(A)$, we can identity $ker(F_A)$ as $(ker(A))^n$. Again, we are viewing a matrix in $M_n(\mathbb C)$ as its tuple of columns in $(\mathbb C^n)^n$. Let $k = dim(ker(A))$. Then in conclusion, $dim(ker(F_A)) = dim(ker(A)^n) = kn$.